# CORS header with no value

Tags: http-headers, cors

What happens when the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` is set to nothing at all? As it expects a `domain.com` or `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the empty string, browsers will log some kind of error to the console—either an error just saying the request origin doesn’t match the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value, or else an error that the empty string is an invalid value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (in browsers which do that validation check).

Either way, browsers won’t ever allow CORS requests from anywhere to access that resource.

Comment: So it would be like not having the header at all?

Comment: The effect would be like not having the header at all—in that all CORS requests would just fail—but the error message would be different; the browser error message if there were no header at all would say, e.g., “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present” (rather than saying the origin doesn’t match the value, or that the header value is invalid).